# How do I get an Icon from a png image?

Tags: wpf, png, icons

I'm creating an WPF app, so I'm mostly working with the ImageSource class for icons. However, the system tray icon has to be of type `System.Drawing.Icon`. Is it possible to create such an object from a png image?

I have tried the following:

```
private static System.Drawing.Icon _pngIcon;
public static System.Drawing.Icon PngIcon
{
    get
    {
        if (_pngIcon == null)
        {  
            //16x16 png image (24 bit or 32bit color)
            System.Drawing.Bitmap icon = global::BookyPresentation.Properties.Resources.star16;
            MemoryStream iconStream = new MemoryStream();
            icon.Save(iconStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            iconStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            _pngIcon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream); //Throws exception
        }
        return _pngIcon;
    }
}
```

The Icon constructor throws an exception with the following message: "Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon."

I figured it might be something with the bit depth of the image color as I had some issues with this earlier, but both 32bit and 24bit images didn't work. Is it possible what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can try something like this before convert your image to .ico:

```
    var bitmap = new Bitmap("Untitled.png"); // or get it from resource
    var iconHandle = bitmap.GetHicon();
    var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle);
```

Where `icon` will contain the icon which you need.

Comment: I only get 16 color icons when I use this method

Comment: remember to dispose the icon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979653/icon-fromhandle-should-i-dispose-it-or-call-destroyicon/33801377#33801377

Answer (score 8):

There's also a website (http://www.convertico.com/) which converts PNGs into ICOs.

Comment: or you just use c# as OP asked.. `new Bitmap("bla.png").GetHicon()`

Comment: @GottZ -- but the OP didn't ask for a C# solution.  He provided code because that's what he's doing, but his question is "how to get a System.Drawing.Icon typed image file for use in his WPF project." specifically from an existing PNG file.  Which nearly 12 years ago, that website did that particular task because I used it for that task.

Answer (score 5):

Icons are a combination of 3 or 4 image sizes:

48 × 48, 32 × 32, 24 × 24 (optional), and 16 × 16 pixels.

And can/should also contain three different colour depths:

- 24-bit with 8-bit alpha (32-bit)
- 8-bit (256 colors) with 1-bit transparency
- 4-bit (16 colors) with 1-bit transparency

So the .png memory stream isn't going to fit into the icon's constructor. In fact, if you read the notes on the other [constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.icon.aspx), you'll see all the "Size" or Width and Height measurements for finding the correct size icon in the file.

More information on the manual creation of icons can be found under "[Creating Windows XP Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx)"

Answer (score 4):

There is a .NET project called [IconLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx).

```
public void Convert(string pngPath, string icoPath)
{
    MultiIcon mIcon = new MultiIcon();
    SingleIcon sIcon = mIcon.Add("Icon1");
    sIcon.CreateFrom(pngPath, IconOutputFormat.FromWin95);
    mIcon.SelectedIndex = 0;
    mIcon.Save(icoPath, MultiIconFormat.ICO);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this its working for me,

```
window.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("YourImage.png",
UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream);
```

Comment: For me this worked with a small modification : `BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Folder/YourImage.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream)`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ImageSource` of a window icon to a png image and it works, surprisingly. I haven't verified this for tray icons though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a small command line app called [png2ico](http://winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/). I use it to create Windows icons from pngs.

Comment: I tried that, but it totally ruined the image on the edges of the transparent areas.