# WPF Application will not start due to a System.IO.FileFormatException()

Tags: .net, wpf

I have written a WPF application in .NET 4.0.

I have installed and successfully run the application on the following operating systems:

- Windows XP SP2
- Vista
- Window 7 (32 bit)
- Windows 7 (64 bit)

After installing the application on a machine with Windows XP SP3, the application failed to start. I checked the Event Viewer's application logs and found the following error:

```
Application: ApplicationName.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileFormatException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.EnsureThumbnail()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.get_Thumbnail()
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.IconHelper.GetBestMatch(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame>, System.Windows.Size)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.IconHelper.CreateIconHandleFromImageSource(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource, System.Windows.Size)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.IconHelper.GetIconHandlesFromImageSource(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource, IconHandle ByRef, IconHandle ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Window.UpdateIcon()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double, Double, Double, Double)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at ApplicationName.App.LoadMainWindow()
   at ApplicationName.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at ApplicationName.App.Main()
```

So I am guessing that it has something to do one of the images I have in one of my windows, but not sure what ;)

Has anyone seen this exception before and have a solution?

Note: In case this is relevant, my installer loads WIC and the full .NET Framework 4.0 onto the target machine, where necessary.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the target machine has the latest service pack of the .NET Framework you're targeting?

Comment: I don't have the machine here but unless I am mistaken the .Net Framework threw the exception. The second line of the error log showed 'Framework Version: v4.0.30319', so I assume that is the version installed.

Comment: If it has something to do with font issue/s, you might want to check this link: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/176008/396460.aspx

Comment: you might be able to locate the image that it is having the problem with by using the sysinternals [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) tool to monitor which files it is accessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have to suggest that possibly the/a window icon file is in `.png` format, converting the file to a `.jpeg` and retrying ought to be worth your while.

Note that intriguingly, debugging with Visual Studio on the seemingly *defective* machine actually doesn't have problems, in my experience.

My apologies that I don't have any references regarding this matter, but it was brought to light to me by self investigation as research turned up less than scarce results. I will try and see if there is any information out there now, as it was some time ago.

EDIT:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9e723d51-0e26-4609-8fe1-5e0edcf7385b

[How do I get an Icon from a png image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384931/how-do-i-get-an-icon-from-a-png-image)

Comment: I removed the icon from the Window as you suggested and I no longer got the exception. I will change the image from .ico to .jpeg and see how that goes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look into the bitiness of your *.ico image/s, it may be part of the problem along with the initial format (I'm no expert in the internal storage of icon files) - try saving your icon with different colour ranges.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/321285/wpf-application-fails-if-window-icon-is-a-vista-ico-file

Comment: My icon was a PNG, converted it to an ICO using Icon Sushi, works fine now.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the hints on same issue.  I found that I had the Icon property set to an ICO within the Shell.xaml Window property.  I removed that which gives the icon-less window when I run in VS.  However I went to the project properties and selected the icon there (VS found the icon in my resources folder-cool!).  When the application builds the EXE the contains the ICO, and a nice surprise is that the window now has the same icon on it.